# AWS Lambda Function to Retrieve Item From DynamoDB Table Using Either Scan or Query

Tags: node.js, post, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

My intention is to write a Lambda function that retrieves the specified item from the DynamoDB table using either Scan or Query (which ever works). This is invoked using a REST post request.

In my current version of my Lambda function, I am able to retrieve all the items from the DynamoDB table by using the ScanCommand and I tried to implement the different FilterExpression parameters and/or ExpressionAttributeValues (when using Query). Unfortunately, I am unsuccessful in querying/retrieving the specific item using the parameter I have defined, petID.

In the table:

sk is the sort key for where the item is retrieved by the requested petID parameter.

```
/**
 * detail lost Pet Lambda Function 
 * Retrieves the singular lost pet using the pet ID / sk 
 * 
 * @param   {module} DynamoDBClient
 * @param   {module} QueryCommand
 * @param   {module} ScanCommand
 * @return  {function}  lambda  invokes post/get request lost pet alert function
 * 
 * @author  
 * @version 1.1
 */
const { DynamoDBClient, QueryCommand, ScanCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb"); // CommonJS import
const aws = require('aws-sdk'); 

/**
 * Exports handler Function
 * Handles nodejs Lambda function using a try-catch statement
 * 
 * @param   {json}  event   Post/Get event parameter
 * @return  {json}  output  REST Post/Get lost pet alert data 
 * @throws  {404}   exception
 * @throws  {xxx}   exception
 *
 * @author  
 * @version 1.1
 */
exports.handler = async (event) => {

    try {

        console.log(event);     // log event parameter post
        
        let body = event.body;  // log event body ensure that it is string
        
        // [object Object]
        let bodyJSON2 = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("bodyJSON2: " +bodyJSON2);
        
        let bodyJSON = JSON.stringify(body); // body JSON from parsed event.body
         
        console.log("bodyJSON: "+bodyJSON);
               
        let petID = bodyJSON.petID;         // pet id param
        
        if(!petID) {
           // throw new Error("Missing petID in request body JSON")
        }
        
        
        /**
         * detail petalert-lost parameters
         * Parameters & Configuration for the table
         * 
         * @param {Table}  petalert-lost        Dynamodb table identifier
         * @param {String} username             User profile identifier
         * @param {String} sk                   pet id identifier
         * @param {String} petname              pet name identifier
         * @param {String} found_desc           found Pet Alert description
         * @param {String} lastSeenTime         Time last seen parameter
         * @param {String} lastSeenLocation     Location last seen parameter
         * @param {String} reward               reward value parameter
         * @param {String} foundTime            foundTime value parameter
         * @param {String} phoneNumber          found phone Number parameter
         * @param {String} status_val           status value parameter
         * @param {Number} longitutde           longitude location parameter
         * @param {Number} latitude             lattitude location parameter
         * @param {String} photo1               photo1 parameter
         * @param {String} photo2               photo2 parameter
         * @param {String} photo3               photo3 parameter
         * @param {String} photo4               photo4 parameter
         * @param {String} phoneNumberAddedTime phone number added time
         * @return {dynamodb params} petalert-found
         * 
         * @author  
         * @version 1.1
         */
        // working scan
        const params = {
            TableName: "petalert-lost",
            Key: {
                "sk": petID
            }
            
            
        };
        
        // query param attempt
        const paramsQUERY = {
            TableName: "petalert-lost",
            KeyConditionExpression: 'sk = :petID',
            FilterExpression : "sk = :petID",
            Key: {
                "sk": petID
            },
            //KeyConditionExpression: "sk = :petID",
            
            // Key: {
            //     "petID": {
            //         S: petID
            //     }
            // },
            
        };


        const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "ap-southeast-1" });    // production client - singapore

        let command = new ScanCommand(params);
     
        const res = await client.send(command);

        console.log(res);

        console.log(res.Items);

        let petList = res.Items; 

        let response;


        /**
         * 200 Status Code
         * Passing Result
         * 
         * @param {Number} res.$metadata.httpStatusCode Containing the HTTP Status Code
         * @param {Struct} allPetList                   Containing the parameter response
         * @return {json}  response                     Json response
         * 
         * @author
         * @version 1.1
         */
        if (res.$metadata.httpStatusCode == 200) {
            response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                "isBase64Encoded": false,
                "headers": { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
                body: JSON.stringify(petList),
            };
            return response;
        }
        /**
         * !200 Status Code
         * Failure Result
         *
         * @param {Number} res.$metadata.httpStatusCode Containing the HTTP Status Code
         * @return {json}  response                     Json response
         * 
         * @author
         * @version 1.1
         */
        else if (res.$metadata.httpStatusCode != 200) {
            response = {
                statusCode: res.$metadata.httpStatusCode,
                "isBase64Encoded": false,
                "headers": { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
                body: JSON.stringify("retrieve detail lost pet alert FAIL"),
            };
            return response;
        }
    }
    /**
    * 456 Status Code
    * Error Exception Result
    * @param {Error} err           Containing error value
    * @return {json}  errResp      Error Json response
    * 
    * @author
    * @version 1.1
    */
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);

        const errResp = {
            //statusCode: err.$metadata.httpStatusCode,
            statusCode: 456,
            "isBase64Encoded": false,
            "headers": { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
            body: JSON.stringify(err.__type),
        };
        return errResp;

    }
    finally {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wish to receive a list of item where `petId` is the key, to use Query `petId` must be the partition key for your table, if it's not then you need to create a GSI and make `petId` the partition key.

I believe `petId` is your sort key by your description and for that reason a Query won't work.

Query would look like this:

```
        const params = {
            TableName: "petalert-lost",
            KeyConditionExpression: 'sk = :petID',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":petID":{"S":petID}
            }
            
        };



let command = new QueryCommand(params);
     
const res = await client.send(command);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have username as my partition key which is why I cannot have pet as my partition key.


I tried your implementation but I think it doesn't work as I used QueryCommand and petID is not a partition key.

Comment: Hi, I read up on what you mean by GSI.

I will try implement this thank you.

Comment: You have 2 options, you can use `Scan` or create a GSI and use `Query`, which would be faster and more efficient